# ADF replace function problems on API-Key

Tags: azure, rest, replace, api-key

I am trying authorizing a POST api in ADF. For some reason the '" is added to in both start and end of what I return from the API.

This is what I receive from the API:
"Response": ""EAAAAOr+T7pLgJ .....

This is the function I use @replace(activity('GetBearerToken').output.Response,'"', '')

This is the result from the function:{
"name": "Token",
"value": ""EAAAAOr+T7

As you see it does not replace the unwanted ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried `replace()` function to replace double quotes(") with null/ empty. Its working perfectly fine. And there is no limitation or blocker documented or notified so far on this function. Could you please recheck once your expression and output jsons.

Please check below link to know more about replace function: [control-flow-replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#replace)